# How to clone a List inside a for Loop in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class MarketStyleTwoOutcome extends StatelessWidget {
  MarketStyleTwoOutcome(this.markets) : marketList = markets.markets;

  final Markets markets;
  final List<Market> marketList;

  List<Market> marketNewList = [];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List market = []..addAll(markets.markets);
    List<Outcome> marketOutcomes = markets.markets[0].outcomes;

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      marketNewList[i] = []..addAll(markets.markets);
    }
```

so my goal is to duplicate markets.markets 3 times, but inside my for loop it seems that I have a code error. I also did try

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      marketNewList.add([]..addAll(markets.markets)); // 
    }
```

and

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      marketNewList.add(List.from(markets.markets)); // 
    }
```

but it seems not to work

Comment: do you want something like this? [marke, market, market] or [[market], [market], [market]]?

Comment: Can you provide the Markets class? I still didn't get what you need. Give us an example of what you need like: [Markets, Markets] or [[Markets],[Markets]].

Comment: [market, market, market] will do

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the *spread operator* is a good way to do this. Try something like this:

```
void main() {
  
  final list = ['hello', 'world'];
  
  var newList = [];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    newList = [...newList, ...list];
  }
  
  print(newList);
}
```